# How to stop and remove a docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, software-uninstall

I'm trying to remove a docker/image/container and all stuff which is somehow connected with docker, but first of all I need to stop it. While I'm trying to execute this command:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

It gives me an error:

```
[:/home/imran] 1 $ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

2015/01/16 00:37:38 Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.14/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied

Usage: docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]  

Stop a running container by sending SIGTERM and then SIGKILL after a grace period

  -t, --time=10      Number of seconds to wait for the container to stop before killing it. Default is 10 seconds.
```

How can I uninstall a docker container?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've fixed it! *Please don't forget - all your data in the containers will be removed!*

**So, first of all we need to execute this commands:**

```
# adding new group
$ sudo groupadd docker

# adding user to the 'docker' group
$ sudo gpasswd -a ${your_username} docker

# restart the docker (documentation suggests to use 'docker.io' instead of 'docker',
# for me both variants work just fine!
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Then we need to logout, **DON'T** use GUI-variant because it didn't work for me and i was dissapointed about this.

**Instead, use this command:**

```
sudo pkill -u username
```

Then we need to...

**1. Kill all running containers**

```
sudo docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

**2. Delete all stopped containers**

```
sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

**3. Delete all 'untagged/dangling' images**

```
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

**4. Delete all images**

```
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

*Sources:*
https://www.calazan.com/docker-cleanup-commands/
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-do-i-log-out-via-terminal-928183/

*P.S. Maybe other answers are correct too, but at the moment these answers were published my problem was already fixed and I'm unable to check if they are correct or not. Thanks to @Andreas. He pointed out a mistake that containers were already removed. Since I didn't find any correct and "all in one" sollution I wanna tell you how you can fix it.*

Comment: How do you remove the remain IP routing from ifconfig?  `docker` still shows up as a network device

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute these commands as `root`, i.e. using `sudo`:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

Or:

```
sudo sh -c "docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)"
```

Comment: Is this a normal output: http://pastebin.com/FXhc5TF7 . Also I've noticed my "cmd-label" is changed. From 'user@rootf8fds7$: ' to '[:/home/imran]'

Comment: Probably this means that there are no running containers. Check by simply running `sudo docker ps`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I've tried another method before you've wrote your answer and this because they don't exist xD. What about problem with "cmd-label"? This is because *docker*. Should I open new thread? I think it will be complicated to understand others what is going on still they won't see this conversation. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: This is indeed probably a separate problem.